# In vim, is it possible to open a file specifying its name case insensitively

Tags: vim, vi

In vim, there is the <kbd>**</kbd> wild card that can be used for file opening using `:e` for instance. The wildcard allows to open for downward search of a file. Is there a way to tweak vim so that the search is case insensitive?

Comment: Are you using "real" vi or a vi clone, such as Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Carpetsmoker` point out:

1. type **`:tabe /path/to/dir`** to browse the path (use **`.`** if already in that dir)
2. type **`/filename\c`** to search you file ignorecase
3. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open your `FileName`

Answer (score 1):

There are a two options which control case matching while searching, `ignorecase` and `smartcase`.

Excerpt from From `:help ignorecase`

> If the 'ignorecase' option is on, the case of normal letters is
>   ignored. 'smartcase' can be set to ignore case when the pattern
>   contains lowercase letters only.
>
> When "\c" appears anywhere in the pattern, the whole pattern is
>   handled like 'ignorecase' is on.  The actual value of 'ignorecase' and
>   'smartcase' is ignored.  "\C" does the opposite: Force matching case
>   for the whole pattern. {only Vim supports \c and \C} Note that
>   'ignorecase', "\c" and "\C" are not used for the character classes.

Additionally, from `:help *`

> 'ignorecase' is used, 'smartcase' is not.

So, setting `ignorecase` (with or without combining it with `smartcase`) should work.

You may also want to combine them in a keybind. For example:

```
:nmap i* :set ignorecase<CR>*
:nmap c* :set noignorecase<CR>*
```

Comment: This doesn't work: I am interested in non-case sensitive matching for the file opening using `:e` or `:tabe`. The `ignorecase` option doesn't affect matching for file opening. I updated the question to clarify this point.

Comment: Ah. That's not quite what you said in your original post. I assumed the ``**`` was a typo because you were talking about "downward search". :) I'll take a look at it when I'm home from work.